# My custom Opencart module logs me out of admin when trying to save

Tags: php, token, opencart

I have built an OpenCart module to add "articles" to the site. I have done this by cloning the "information" module and then adapting it to my needs.

I have made a lot of progress - pretty much finished what I set out to do - and **everything works fine on my local dev server.** Problem is I've pushed it up to the live server and when I enter the article details and press save (in the admin area) it immediately logs me out, and nothing is saved at all.

My feeling is that it has something to do with the token that gets added when I log in because when I save and I get logged out that token number (appended to the url) is different.

I don't know php all that well (have a background in C# and .NET) but generally understand what's going on. I hope someone can help out.

The Controller file for article: (let me know if any other files/info is needed)

```
class ControllerCatalogArticle extends Controller { 
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('catalog/article');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('catalog/article');

        $this->getList();
    }

    public function insert() {
        $this->load->language('catalog/article');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('catalog/article');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
            $this->model_catalog_article->addArticle($this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
        }

        $this->getForm();
    }

    public function update() {
        $this->load->language('catalog/article');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('catalog/article');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
            $this->model_catalog_article->editArticle($this->request->get['article_id'], $this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
        }

        $this->getForm();
    }

    public function delete() {
        $this->load->language('catalog/article');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('catalog/article');

        if (isset($this->request->post['selected']) && $this->validateDelete()) {
            foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $article_id) {
                $this->model_catalog_article->deleteArticle($article_id);
            }

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
        }

        $this->getList();
    }

    private function getList() {
        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'id.title';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $this->data['insert'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article/insert', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
        $this->data['delete'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article/delete', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'); 

        $this->data['articles'] = array();

        $data = array(
            'sort'  => $sort,
            'order' => $order,
            'start' => ($page - 1) * $this->config->get('config_admin_limit'),
            'limit' => $this->config->get('config_admin_limit')
        );


        $article_total = $this->model_catalog_article->getTotalArticles();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_article->getArticles($data);

        $this->load->model('catalog/article_category');
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $action = array();

            $action[] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_edit'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('catalog/article/update', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&article_id=' . $result['article_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
            );

            $this->data['articles'][] = array(
                'article_id' => $result['article_id'],
                'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                'title'          => $result['title'],
                'sort_order'     => $result['sort_order'],
                'selected'       => isset($this->request->post['selected']) && in_array($result['article_id'], $this->request->post['selected']),
                'action'         => $action,
                'article_category' =>   $this->model_catalog_article_category->getArticleCategoryTitle($result['category_id'])
            );

        }   

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');

        $this->data['column_title'] = $this->language->get('column_title');
        $this->data['column_article_category'] = $this->language->get('column_article_category');       
        $this->data['column_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('column_sort_order');
        $this->data['column_action'] = $this->language->get('column_action');       

        $this->data['button_insert'] = $this->language->get('button_insert');
        $this->data['button_delete'] = $this->language->get('button_delete');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
            $this->data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

            unset($this->session->data['success']);
        } else {
            $this->data['success'] = '';
        }

        $url = '';

        if ($order == 'ASC') {
            $url .= '&order=DESC';
        } else {
            $url .= '&order=ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->data['sort_title'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&sort=id.title' . $url, 'SSL');
        $this->data['sort_sort_order'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&sort=i.sort_order' . $url, 'SSL');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $article_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = $this->config->get('config_admin_limit');
        $pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');
        $pagination->url = $this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', 'SSL');

        $this->data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

        $this->data['sort'] = $sort;
        $this->data['order'] = $order;

        $this->template = 'catalog/article_list.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

    private function getForm() {
        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['text_default'] = $this->language->get('text_default');
        $this->data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $this->data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

        $this->data['entry_title'] = $this->language->get('entry_title');
        $this->data['entry_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_description');
        $this->data['entry_meta_title'] = $this->language->get('entry_meta_title');
        $this->data['entry_meta_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_meta_description');
        $this->data['entry_meta_keywords'] = $this->language->get('entry_meta_keywords');
        $this->data['entry_abstract'] = $this->language->get('entry_abstract');
        $this->data['entry_article_category'] = $this->language->get('entry_article_category');
        $this->data['entry_store'] = $this->language->get('entry_store');
        $this->data['entry_keyword'] = $this->language->get('entry_keyword');
        $this->data['entry_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');
        $this->data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');
        $this->data['entry_layout'] = $this->language->get('entry_layout');

        $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
        $this->data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

        $this->data['tab_general'] = $this->language->get('tab_general');
        $this->data['tab_data'] = $this->language->get('tab_data');
        $this->data['tab_design'] = $this->language->get('tab_design');

        $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['title'])) {
            $this->data['error_title'] = $this->error['title'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_title'] = array();
        }

        if (isset($this->error['description'])) {
            $this->data['error_description'] = $this->error['description'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_description'] = array();
        }

        if (isset($this->error['category'])) {
            $this->data['error_category'] = $this->error['category'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_category'] = array();
        }



        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),            
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        if (!isset($this->request->get['article_id'])) {
            $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article/insert', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
        } else {
            $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article/update', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&article_id=' . $this->request->get['article_id'] . $url, 'SSL');
        }

        $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('catalog/article', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');

        if (isset($this->request->get['article_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
            $article_info = $this->model_catalog_article->getArticle($this->request->get['article_id']);
        }

        $this->load->model('localisation/language');        
        $this->data['languages'] = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();

        if (isset($this->request->post['article_description'])) {
            $this->data['article_description'] = $this->request->post['article_description'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['article_id'])) {
            $this->data['article_description'] = $this->model_catalog_article->getArticleDescriptions($this->request->get['article_id']);
        } else {
            $this->data['article_description'] = array();
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/article');

        $this->data['article_categories'] = $this->model_catalog_article->getArticleCategoriesSort();

        if (isset($this->request->post['select_categories'])) {
            $this->data['category_id'] = $this->request->post['select_categories'];

        } elseif (!empty($article_info)) {
            $this->data['category_id'] = $article_info['category_id'];

        } else {
            $this->data['category_id'] = 0;

        } 


        if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
            $this->data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
        } elseif (!empty($article_info)) {
            $this->data['status'] = $article_info['status'];
        } else {
            $this->data['status'] = 1;
        }

        $this->load->model('setting/store');

        $this->data['stores'] = $this->model_setting_store->getStores();

        if (isset($this->request->post['article_store'])) {
            $this->data['article_store'] = $this->request->post['article_store'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['article_id'])) {
            $this->data['article_store'] = $this->model_catalog_article->getArticleStores($this->request->get['article_id']);
        } else {
            $this->data['article_store'] = array(0);
        }       

        if (isset($this->request->post['keyword'])) {
            $this->data['keyword'] = $this->request->post['keyword'];
        } elseif (!empty($article_info)) {
            $this->data['keyword'] = $article_info['keyword'];
        } else {
            $this->data['keyword'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['sort_order'])) {
            $this->data['sort_order'] = $this->request->post['sort_order'];
        } elseif (!empty($article_info)) {
            $this->data['sort_order'] = $article_info['sort_order'];
        } else {
            $this->data['sort_order'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['article_layout'])) {
            $this->data['article_layout'] = $this->request->post['article_layout'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['article_id'])) {
            $this->data['article_layout'] = $this->model_catalog_article->getArticleLayouts($this->request->get['article_id']);
        } else {
            $this->data['article_layout'] = array();
        }   

        $this->load->model('design/layout');

        $this->data['layouts'] = $this->model_design_layout->getLayouts();

        $this->template = 'catalog/article_form.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

    private function validateForm() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/article')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }   

        foreach ($this->request->post['article_description'] as $language_id => $value) {           
            if ((utf8_strlen($value['title']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($value['title']) > 64)) {
                $this->error['title'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_title');
            }       
            if (utf8_strlen($value['description']) < 3) {
                $this->error['description'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_description');
            }   


        }

        if ($this->error && !isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_warning');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function validateDelete() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/article')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        $this->load->model('setting/store');

        foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $article_id) {
            if ($this->config->get('config_account_id') == $article_id) {
                $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_account');
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_checkout_id') == $article_id) {
                $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_checkout');
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_affiliate_id') == $article_id) {
                $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_affiliate');
            }

            $store_total = $this->model_setting_store->getTotalStoresByArticleId($article_id);

            if ($store_total) {
                $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_store'), $store_total);
            }
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this only happen when you use the article area, or does it log your out fairly quickly when you use the admin generally?

Comment: It only happens when I use the new article area. There's no problem with using the admin area in general - everything else works fine.

Comment: From my quick scan over it, it looks fine. Do you have any AJAX on the article page?

Comment: I haven't added any AJAX to the article page (on either back or frontend).  Could there be an issue with the template / view file?

Comment: possibly, though unlikely. open the article editor page, and view source, then find the form and check that the token is present in there correctly in the action="..."

Comment: I checked the source and it is there:    
>    <form action="http://mydomain.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/article/insert&amp;token=f2742cc86df80fd5fb1fefa6878bd200" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make the code show as code and not a link as above.

Comment: hmm, it all looks correct from what I can see. If it works locally it just makes me think it's a server issue

Comment: darn, ok I'll have to see if I can make another plan. thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: +1 - your question answered a question I had about getting the token.  Hope you worked it all out!

Comment: A couple of things I noticed: You're loading your models twice. If you load it in `update()` you don't need to load it inside `getForm()` as this is a private function called inside the class and is already loaded.  I can't put this up live and test it for you since I don't have all the rest of the files, but I don't agree that it's a server issue, if your other forms post ok then it doesn't make sense that the server would be missing something that's needed. The best way to test is to create break points and see where it's logging you out.